# standalone eloquent does not save bigint value in remote mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I use standalone eloquent for one of my php project and everything was ok but when I move my mysql database to a remote server I found a bug that bigint value does not save to my table in database.

The field is bigint and also the value that I wanted to save is ok.

Also I can save my value in mysql with phpmyadmin but I can not do that with eloquent.

I really appreciate if can help me.

Comment: What's the value of the bigint? Are you working in a 32bit or 64bit environment?

Comment: 64 bit environment and the value is for example something like this 153077153287

Comment: What about MySQL versions, are they same? Whats the error you are getting? I bet its application error not Eloquent / Database error. Post code / errors etc. without it we are going blind.

Comment: It was working until I move my server so It could not be an application error